# Prediction using mboost multinomial logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I am trying to use the mboost package in R to apply a multinomial logistic regression model. I found this example online but I added the "newdata = iris" in the predict function to see how the prediction formula worked in mboost for new data. I am getting an error however. First here is the code:

```
library(mboost)

### fitting multinomial logit model via a linear array model
X0 <- K0 <- diag(nlevels(iris$Species) - 1)
colnames(X0) <- levels(iris$Species)[-nlevels(iris$Species)]
mlm <- mboost(Species ~ bols(Sepal.Length, df = 2) %O%
            buser(X0, K0, df = 2), data = iris,
          family = Multinomial())
round(predict(mlm, type = "response", newdata = iris), 2)
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:
    Error in `[.data.frame`(newdata, nm) : undefined columns selected

I just re-used the iris data in the prediction just as a test but has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: `round(predict(mlm, type = "response"), 2)` works for me.

Comment: Aye, that was the unedited example taken from the web. I'm looking to predict on new data. I used the iris dataset as a "new" dataset just for test purposes so it is my fault for the confusion.

Comment: I submitted an issue with the developer on [github](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost/issues/13).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you cannot use the `predict` function with new data is that you use pre-defined design and penalty matrices in `buser()`, i.e., `X0` and `K0`. These are not part of the new data set and thus are not available when building new design matrices for prediction.

Sarah Brockhaus postet a [solution](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost/issues/13#issuecomment-124031925) on github that replaces `buser` with `bols`. To do this one needs to convert the data set to a list and add the new `dummy` to this list. If one really wants to predict with new data, one needs to keep this `dummy` untouched. See also my post on [github](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost/issues/13#issuecomment-124095614).

[Edit] As @Lorcan-Treanor mentions in his comments, the number of factors needed for `bols` is not always equal to two. Here it actually is `nlevels(iris$Species) - 1`, i.e., one less factor level than we have classes in the outcome. I've also updated my post on github accordingly.

Comment: Looks good, cheers for that. Before I give you the thumbs up, if I can ask one stupid question. Is the factor(1:2) for the dummy used because we have 3-1 classes (setosa, versicolor and virginica) or because I use df = 3-1 in the buser or now bols argument?

Comment: Actually never mind, sussed it out and it is because of the number of classes. Apologies and thank you and Sarah for your efforts. I like this package because of the success I had with the glmboost function and I am new to boosting techniques so thank you.